# Downloading large pdf fails

Tags: chromium

I tried downloading ***Arm Architecture Reference Manual Armv8, for Armv8-A architecture profile***, which is about 8500 pages.  My download succeeds when using my Intel-based laptop, Windows 10, and Firefox.  When I try the same file (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/fc/?search=5eec7399e24a5e02d07b2754) with my RPi, The download box at the bottom of the screen says it is a 48MB file which, when clicked on, only shows a black background with a puzzle piece icon with a sad face (which I assume means the file is corrupt).

Any suggestions as to how I can get the download to succeed?

Let me know if there is more info that I should gather.

---

Raspberry Pi info:
Rpi 4B 8Gb Raspbian, 32Gb sd card

Chromium version info:
Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 10 (32-bit)

Comment: Didi the download stop half way? What does `df` say?

Comment: Seems to work after the current update and upgrade sequence.

Answer (score 4):

> Any suggestions as to how I can get the download to succeed?

Maybe there is a problem with Chromium or with the GUI? You can try to use the command line (always a good idea on Unix if things making trouble ;-). Be sure that you have at least 50MB of free space on the SD Card. Execute this command:

```
rpi ~$ wget -O DDI0487Fc_armv8_arm.pdf https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f20515cbb903e39c84dc459?token=
```

On my RasPi 4B it works and I get the complete manual **DDI0487Fc_armv8_arm.pdf** with a size of 48MB and with 8248 pages.

Comment: Could you give us a brief summary of that document in a comment, please ?  :)

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, but I don't understand it. it's the detailed description of the ARM architecture. You can just copy and paste the given command and look what's written.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After the usual update and upgrade, the DL seems to work (finally).  Strange that the DL didn't work before now, especially with no error messages, but I guess that's the way RPi packages operate.  Nothing against the RPi (I'm using it for my "desktop"), but testing RPi apps most likely doesn't get the attention they deserve.